# Casting Anonymous type throws casting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, type-conversion

In my Global.asax file i have created and array list which contains an anonymous type object

```
Application["userRecordsCountList"] = new ArrayList();

((System.Collections.ArrayList)Application["userRecordsCountList"]).Add(new { userCount = 12, logTime = DateTime.Now });
```

now in my cs file i have a casting function which goes like this

```
T Cast<T>(object obj, T type)
{
    return (T)obj;
}
```

now when i run the loop to iterate the data and extract the data in data set i get an error
see the code

```
ArrayList countRecord = new ArrayList((System.Collections.ArrayList)Application["userRecordsCountList"]);

foreach (var item in countRecord)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        var record = Cast(item, new { userCount = "", logTime = "" });
        dr["Time"] = record.logTime;
        dr["Users"] = record.userCount;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

error is

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.DateTime]' to type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]'.
```

please help me out.. I have tried every method i found on stackoverflow or any other sources.....

thnx

Comment: Did you read the message? Your types are wrong.

Comment: What is the signature/code of your method `Cast()`?

Comment: @SLaks Thats not the issue...run the code and check it urself

Comment: Did you read the error message? That is the issue.

Comment: I tried even giving same types.... The error remains same...

Answer (score 6):

Don't use an anonymous type - use the actual type you need. Anonymous types can only be using within a method - they can't be passed in as parameters ore return types and are not suitable for serialization in general.

Additionally, you shouldn't use `ArrayList` - it is not type safe. Use a generic collection like `List<T>` instead.

Comment: ohk i'll try not to use it..but I really want to know the solution to this problem!!!!

Answer (score 0):

They're not compatible types.  The error message gives the error.  One is an anonymous type with `int` and `DateTime` properties.  The second has `string` and `string` as properties.

You can only cast to either the actual type, or a base class, and anonymous types don't have a base class other than `object` so that's the only thing you can cast them to.

This is probably what you want:

```
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Time"] = item.logTime.ToString();
    dr["Users"] = item.userCount.ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Or as Oded says, use a real type.

Comment: Davy the case you are talking is not what the exact error is... please run the code and check

Answer (score 0):

The one demonstrated in your code is not an ideal example for Anonymous type. I would rather use anonymous type for a method level scope, preferably with some Linq.

While I agree it is cumbersome to create a class/model for each combination of objects. Thus, in your case you can consider using a generic Pair class, just to store DateTime and int in a paired object. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb439273.aspx).

So, your collection would become:

```
(List<Pair<int,DateTime>>Application["userRecordsCountList"]).Add(new Pair<int,DateTime>(12, DateTime.Now));
```